# XNA 4 reach profile causes exception and Hidef doesn't compile

Tags: graphics, xna-4.0

I want to run Xna project on my laptop ,when I run the project using HiDef profile
I have a massege

> No suitable graphic card found. Couldn't find Direct3D device that support the XNA Framework HiDef profile

And when I change the profile to Reach the project run but throw an exception

> XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two.

Is there any way to run the project using Hidef profile? I am sure that the graphic driver works correctly. I have Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD.

If there isn't answer, how can I remove the above exception?

Comment: Try updating your graphics card drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception 1:

This tool from microsoft will detail the problem with your graphics card:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/graphics_profile_checker

Exception 2:

Use textures power of two. 
 Go to your content project and select your textures, in the properties windows expand the processor properties, enable to true the property "Convert textures to power of two" (or similar)